# How to make multiple buttons open the same activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-button

I am new to Android and Java development 
and I am wondering how to make the buttons in the dashboard open the same activity but with different data 
for each fragment . this activity will work the same way for all the buttons the only thing changing is the `sortalgorithm.java`  used

Comment: Please post you code and show what data you want to show. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put a flag in your intent when you call startActivity(Intent intent) method. is something like this:

```java
//...
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);          
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("whatFragment","1");
intent.putExtra("extras",b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then you catch this in your Fragment with:

```java
            /*
            .
            .
            .
             */

            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            String whatFrag=b.getString("extras");
            if(whatFrag.equals("1")){
                //code if fragment selected is 1
            }
            /*
            .
            .
            .
             */
```